# HTTP Error 500 in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've just been trying to fix a clients Wordpress... I added a bit of code to both the Theme functions and the main blog page and now I am receiving an http 500 error. How could I resolve this issue? I cannot access the Wordpress Dashboard or the website.

Comment: look in your error logs and paste what error it gives. otherwise there is no way for us to help you. Usually a 500 error within a cms system usually means you have some code that is erroring out and the cms framework cannot handle it.

Comment: Hi @PatrickEvans nothing is showing in the error logs

Comment: if you made an error in the theme functions, you would get a 500 error, and keep in mind with wordpress the theme functions if using a CHILD theme, you don't add the same code twice ... child and parent work in conjuction with eachotehr the child doesn't replace the parent.  BUT 500 error for the wordpress dashboard would not be caused by an error in theme functions. Are you sure you didn't change any plugin settings? or wordpress actual files instead of the themes?

Comment: Nope, I changed code in the main blog list php and functions.php there isn't a child theme

Comment: check your php apache config settings to make sure they are outputting error messages. both have a error level that it will output and you have to set them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Log in through FTP and download the files you edited last.
Than unmake the changes and upload back to the server.

It looks like the changes you have made are making some internal server error.
check your php grammer.

Comment: how did you tried to? 
what changes have you made?
would you like to send me the file and that i would take a look on it?

Comment: I replaced the main blog php via ftp with the original and I edited the functions.php to how it was

Comment: and it still does not work?
can you send me the files you edited that caused it?